# Getting all foreign keys from a QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models, Story and FollowUp. FollowUp can have a foreign key of Story. Story has a foreign key of User.

I can get all Story that are associated with a User with user.story_set.all().  I would like to, without iterating through the queryset, be able to get all FollowUps associated with all the Storys.

I had initially tried user.story_set.all().followup_set.all(), but that does not work.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way would be to use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to preload all the objects, and then just iterate:

```
followups = []
for story in user.story_set.all().prefetch_related():
    followups.extend(story.followup_set.all())
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
followups = Followup.objects.filter(story__in = user.story_set.all())
```

(The second piece of code might need a list compression to use IDs and not objects, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

A more concise approach is:

```
FollowUp.objects.filter(story__user=user)
```